# Using CSS For Two-Dimensional Div Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to flex the contents of my page both vertically and horizontally and for the most part, I've achieved that effect.  However, some of my "rows" are stretching beyond the sizes I've defined for them.  I've recreated my environment [here](https://jsfiddle.net/La3bcqkx/1/).  I can't seem to figure out why the borders for the `topHalf` divs are extending up so far into the `menuBar` div.

```css
html, body, #page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#menuBar {
  height: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#topHalf,
#bottomHalf {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

#topHalf {
  height: 50%;
}

#bottomHalf {
  height: 45%;
}

#menuPanel,
#storagePanel,
#equipmentPanel,
#statsPanel,
#mapPanel,
#craftingPanel,
#utilityPanel {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="menuBar">
    <div id="menuPanel">
      <h3>Menu</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="topHalf">
    <div id="storagePanel">
      <h3>Inventory</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="equipmentPanel">
      <h3>Equipment</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="statsPanel">
      <h3>Stats</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomHalf">
    <div id="mapPanel">
      <h3>Map</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="craftingPanel">
      <h3>Crafting</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="utilityPanel">
      <h3>Utilities</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're actually looking for? It looks like what is happening is the menu is overflowing down into the "topHalf" container. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Checkout `display: grid` this allows you to layout in 2-dimensions .
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: The effect I would like to achieve would look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/foL84c71/1/) with all of the panels vertically flexed.  My goal is to make everything anchored in place and in relation to each other panel as the window is resized and I'd like them all to fit the height and width of the window accordingly.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a jsfiddle which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one: [mcve]

Comment: The jsfiddle is forked and static and will remain unchanged.  But I will edit the question to include my markup as well.

Comment: The question has been updated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/La3bcqkx/3/).

---

And here's what I used:

```css
#page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#page > * {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
#menuBar {
  flex-grow: 0;  
}
```

I also removed the hard-coded heights from all children of `#page`.

---

> **Ref**: *I can't seem to figure out why the borders for the topHalf divs are extending up so far into the menuBar div.*

The reason for the border overlapping effect is `#menuBar` exceeds `5%` of its parent height.
What you probably want is for it to take up the space it needs, but not more (it's the only child of `#page` that shouldn't grow).
The rest of the children should grow equally in the remaining available height.

`min-height:100vh` makes `#page` at least `100%` of the devices' screen height. If the children of `#page` do not fit inside a single screen height, it will develop a scrollbar (and that's probably what you want - you want all content accessible).

Comment: Thank you, this looks great.  But are you saying that there's no way to vertically flex the contents so that regardless of the window size, the divs will all maintain their aspect ratio?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I'm just saying it's bad practice. When viewed on a mobile device in landscape mode, `5%` of viewport height doesn't even allow a single row of text, nevermind padding. When viewed on portrait mobile devices or on large monitors, `5%` might be too much. So why use it if most of the time looks bad? Why do you think most menus have fixed height, on all websites? Look: at [so] menu: `top-bar { height: 60px;}`

Comment: Ahh fair enough.  Well thank you so much.  This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove `height:5%` from `#menuBar`
I think you are looking for this. After removing the `height` the layout looks proper.I added snippet here.

```css
html, body, #page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menuBar {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#topHalf,
#bottomHalf {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

#topHalf {
  height: 50%;
  
}

#bottomHalf {
  height: 45%;
}

#menuPanel,
#storagePanel,
#equipmentPanel,
#statsPanel,
#mapPanel,
#craftingPanel,
#utilityPanel {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="menuBar">
    <div id="menuPanel">
      <h3>Menu</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="topHalf">
    <div id="storagePanel">
      <h3>Inventory</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="equipmentPanel">
      <h3>Equipment</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="statsPanel">
      <h3>Stats</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomHalf">
    <div id="mapPanel">
      <h3>Map</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="craftingPanel">
      <h3>Crafting</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="utilityPanel">
      <h3>Utilities</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. to vertically align.

```css
html, body, #page {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menuBar {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#topHalf,
#bottomHalf {
  display: flex-row;
  position: relative;
}

#topHalf {
  height: 50%;
  
}

#bottomHalf {
  height: 45%;
}

#menuPanel,
#storagePanel,
#equipmentPanel,
#statsPanel,
#mapPanel,
#craftingPanel,
#utilityPanel {
  padding: 25px;
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="menuBar">
    <div id="menuPanel">
      <h3>Menu</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="topHalf">
    <div id="storagePanel">
      <h3>Inventory</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="equipmentPanel">
      <h3>Equipment</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="statsPanel">
      <h3>Stats</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomHalf">
    <div id="mapPanel">
      <h3>Map</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="craftingPanel">
      <h3>Crafting</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="utilityPanel">
      <h3>Utilities</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does fix the overlapping error, but then the contents extend beyond the height of the page and it has to be scrolled...

Comment: Ok.. I have modified the same in the snippet. What you need to do is remove `html, body, #page` `height:100%;` . The `height` will be taken automatically.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't flex the panels vertically anymore when you remove that though.  I read somewhere that if you don't specify the height of your html body then it won't vertically flex the contents accordingly.

Comment: as the `#page` is not a flex box so no need to worry about the vertical alignment of it's inner divs. But `topHalf ` & `bottomHalf` is flex so it will accept the `display`: `flex-row`

Comment: added the snippet for vertically align inner divs

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/La3bcqkx/1/

Remove the default margin of the h3. And the padding of the div make them bigger than the % stated.

```
#menuBar h3 {
    margin:0;
}
#menuBar {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Use border-box to solve the padding issue.

Also read: https://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html